# Exportar uma coleção mongodb que traga também o tamanho do documento

Tags: mongodb

Eu tenho a exportação de um collection que possui algums documentos, preciso fazer a exportação de um destes documentos e seu tamanho.
Eu tentei algo dessa natureza:

```js
mongoexport -d test -c records -q '{ a: { $gte: 3 } }' --out exportdir/myRecords.json
```

Não rolou o que preciso.

Existe alguma função que retorne o tamanho de um documento no collection do mongodb?

Comment: "tamanho" você se refere a quantidade de registros (root) ou tamanho em bytes?

Comment: Refiro-me a quantidade de registros!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carlos o comando que retorna a quantidade de registros é o

`db.collection.count()`